# unbox a property value using a path

Tags: javascript

Having

```
var path = "a.b.c";
var foo = {a: {b: {c: "bar"}}};
```

How to get the `"bar"` from `foo` and `path`?

Surely the `foo['a']['b']['c']` will work but how to get it nicely?

Comment: seems the `'a.b.c'.split('.').reduce((p,c)=>p&&p[c]||null, foo)` solves it, thanks @Dekel & @Adriano Spadoni

Answer (score 0):

Manually handling it would be great trouble. Try this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path

Comment: thanks, but , no, I need pure and simple javascript solution

Comment: Are you looking for a dynamic solution with a variable length of `path` like `path = "a.b.c.d.e..."` or just a static solution for this three levelled structure ?

Comment: it seems the "great troube" is this one: `'a.b.c'.split('.').reduce((p,c)=>p&&p[c]||null, foo)`